# Why is Django not saving to database?

Tags: python, django

I believe I have the correct code, but when I submit the form, nothing is saved to the database. I have debugged the code and the data from the form is being sent via POST, it' just that nothing is being saved to the database:

**views.py**

```
def sign_up_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            user_object = p_form.save()
            user_object.save()
            return redirect('sign_in_photo_verify')
    else:
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/sign-up-post.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image',
                  'city',
                  'state',
                  'zip',
                  ]
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(
        default='default.jpg',
        verbose_name='Profile Image',
        max_length=255,
        storage=FileSystemStorage(location=UPLOAD_DIR, base_url='/media/uploads/'))
    verification_image = models.ImageField(
        default=None,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Verification Image',
        max_length=255,
        storage=FileSystemStorage(location=UPLOAD_DIR, base_url='/media/uploads/'))
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def is_approved(self):
        return self.approved

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def verification_image_tag(self):
        from django.utils.html import escape
        from django.utils.html import mark_safe
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" />' % escape(self.verification_image.url))
    verification_image_tag.short_description = 'Verification Image'
    verification_image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: Most likely it's not valid, look at the form.errors

Comment: You need to re-display the form in case it is not valid.

Comment: What do you mean? if p_form.is_valid() = false, then it drops out of the if/else statement.

Comment: what are your HTML Form codes?
Did you checked the name if Inputs inside form?